# Python pandas resample by day & find middle day of month data

Tags: python, pandas

After converting my input monthly data into daily data via resampling by D and cubic interpolation. I want to find the data for the middle day of each month. But I get error with the below code:
**AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'days'**

Thank you

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel(input_file, sheet_name='mthly', usecols='A:D', na_values='ND', index_col=0, header=0)
df.index.names = ['Period']
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

q= pd.Series(df[series], index=df.index)
d = q.resample('D').interpolate(method='cubic')  
m=d[lambda x: x.index.days==round(x.index.daysinmonth/2)]
```

**INPUT MONTHLY DATA**

```
Period  Values
Jan-22  1
Feb-22  3
Mar-22  7
Apr-22  5
May-22  4
```

**After re-sampling by day and with cubic interpolation**

```
1/1/2022 0:00   1
2/1/2022 0:00   0.884487406
3/1/2022 0:00   0.78564987
4/1/2022 0:00   0.703003964
5/1/2022 0:00   0.636066259
6/1/2022 0:00   0.584353327
7/1/2022 0:00   0.547381739
8/1/2022 0:00   0.524668066
9/1/2022 0:00   0.51572888
10/1/2022 0:00  0.520080751
11/1/2022 0:00  0.537240252
12/1/2022 0:00  0.566723954
13/1/2022 0:00  0.608048428
14/1/2022 0:00  0.660730245
15/1/2022 0:00  0.724285976
16/1/2022 0:00  0.798232194
17/1/2022 0:00  0.882085469
18/1/2022 0:00  0.975362373
19/1/2022 0:00  1.077579477
20/1/2022 0:00  1.188253353
21/1/2022 0:00  1.306900571
22/1/2022 0:00  1.433037703
23/1/2022 0:00  1.566181321
24/1/2022 0:00  1.705847996
25/1/2022 0:00  1.851554299
26/1/2022 0:00  2.002816801
27/1/2022 0:00  2.159152074
28/1/2022 0:00  2.32007669
29/1/2022 0:00  2.485107218
30/1/2022 0:00  2.653760232
31/1/2022 0:00  2.825552302
and so on
```

**Desired Output**

```
16/1/2022 0:00  0.798232194
14/2/2022 0:00  5.289522142
and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the day you should use access the `day` attribute also note that `round` can't be directly applied to `DateTimeIndex` instead you can do a floor division

```
d[d.index.day == d.index.daysinmonth // 2]
```

---

```
              Values
Period              
2022-01-15  0.724286
2022-02-14  5.289522
2022-03-15  6.728110
2022-04-15  3.740278
```